# Getting pop-up error "Netscape.cfg/AutoConfig failed" when trying to drive firefox via selenium Grid using Watir-Webdriver

Tags: firefox, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid2

Get Error:

```
Netscape.cfg/AutoConfig failed. Please contact your system administrator.
 Error:  defaultPref failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code:  0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.setBoolPref]"  nsresult:  "0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)"  location: "JS frame :: prefcalls.js  ::  defaultPref :: line 58"  data: no]

Netscape.cfg/AutoConfig failed. Error:  defaultPref failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code:  0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)
```

I have the following setup:

Selenium Grid on CentOs 6.4

Slave Node = CentOs 6.4

Trying to run Firefox remotely via Watir-WebDriver

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
#require "selenium"
require "watir-webdriver"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
#caps.version = "24"
caps[:name] = "Firefox 24  , port 5555"

default_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default" 
default_profile.native_events = true 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => default_profile)

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new(
    :remote,
    :url => "http://vm-auto.his.vm:4444/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => caps)

    @browser.goto "google.com"
    @browser.text_field(:name => "q").set "3M"
    @browser.button.click
    @browser.div(:id => "resultStats").wait_until_present
    @browser.screenshot.save ("GoogleSearch_FF24.png")
    @browser.close
```

Firefox version is Mozilla Firefox 24.7.0

there is a reference to this error in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=717438

the resolution being suggested as:

```
In my case commenting out this pref in mozilla.cfg stops generating this message.
But I do not know origin of this pref.

//stops the request to send performance data from displaying
//pref("toolkit.telemetry.prompted", true);
```

But, i could not find mozilla.cfg on the filesystem where firefox is installed

Answer (score 1):

That error definitely seems to be related to a problem in the mozilla config file **BUT** in *my* case the file was not `mozilla.cfg` but `mozilla-lock.cfg` (located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\`).

The filename is dictated by the `lockset.js` file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\`.  The line is `pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla-lock.cfg")`

My issue with the config file was the following lines:

```
lockpref("security.tls.version.min", "1");
lockpref("security.tls.version.max", "3");
```

The values should be without quotes:

```
lockpref("security.tls.version.min", 1);
lockpref("security.tls.version.max", 3);
```

As addendum, it's entirely possible you don't have a config file at all and the problem exists with a manual configuration in the `about:config`. Open up the about:config page, and sort by 'status' to look for 'locked', 'user set' or any other non 'default' items.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Firefox 24 ESR. Mozilla.cfg was in the same directory as the Firefox executable.
In my case this was under "%localappdata%\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration[Unique-Code]\Root".
I commented out 'pref("toolkit.telemetry.prompted", true);' and the error message didn't appear anymore.